# С++ Эффективное вычисление произведения матриц

Tags: c++, матрицы, время

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём причина существования разницы во времени в следующих вариантах вычисления произведения двух квадратных матриц? (С++)

- Перемножение двух квадратных матриц, сохранённых в двумерных массивах с указателями
- Такое же перемножение (двумерные массивы), только с предварительным транспонированием одной из матриц
- Перемножение двух матриц, сохранённых в одномерных массивах
- Такое же перемножение (одномерные массивы), только с предварительным транспонированием одной из матриц

Также какой из способов самый быстрый/медленный и почему?

Comment: Погугли pointer chasing.

Comment: Так вам причина, или какой самый быстрый? :) Если последнее - то напишите и посмотрите...

Comment: перемножение двух матриц без предварительных операций, с сохранением где угодно.

Comment: Почитайте книгу *Дж Деммель "Вычислительная линейная алгебра"*. Там описаны способы максимально увеличить скорость перемножения матриц (эти методы используются в библиотеке BLAS). Если кратко, то все зависит от размеров матриц: если обе полностью помещаются в кэш 1 уровня процессора, то в перечисленных Вами способах разницы Вы можете не заметить, если матрицы не влезают в кэш - там начинается всё интересное. И самый быстрый способ - это делить матрицы на отдельные блоки, которые помещаются в кэш. Но, все-равно, библиотеки OpenBLAS и Intel MKL перемножат намного быстрее :-).